# I don't understand how parameters and arguments work together

Tags: c++

I have a problem understanding how each function knows what some variable is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"

double getTowerHeight()
{

    std::cout << "enter the height of the tower in meters: ";
    double towerHeight{};
    std::cin >> towerHeight;

    return towerHeight;
}

double calculateHeight(double towerHeight, int seconds)
{
    double distanceFallen{ (gravity * (seconds * seconds)) / 2.0 };
    double currentHeight{ towerHeight - distanceFallen };

    return currentHeight;
}

void printHeight(double height, int seconds)
{
    if (height > 0.0)
        std::cout << " At " << seconds << " seconds, the ball is at height: " << height << " meters\n";
    else
        std::cout << " At " << seconds << " seconds, the ball is on the ground\n";

}

void calculateAndPrintHeight(double towerHeight, int seconds)
{

    double height{ calculateHeight(towerHeight, seconds) };
    printHeight(height, seconds);
}

int main()
{

    const double towerHeight{ getTowerHeight() };

    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 0);
    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 1);
    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 2);
    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 3);
    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 4);
    calculateAndPrintHeight(towerHeight, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

So how this works? The first line in the main function creates a const variable "towerHeight" and calls a function "getTowerHeight()", I understand. Then it calls function "calculateAndPrintHeight" and the function's parameter creates "double height" and "int seconds", how the function knows what height is, seconds in other functions is...

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```cpp
const double towerHeight{ getTowerHeight() };
```

First, `getTowerHeight()` function is called and the returned value is used to initialize the `towerHeight` variable.
It is equivalent in effect to:

```cpp
const double towerHeight = getTowerHeight();
```

In general,

```cpp
typename varname{value};
```

acheives the same effect as:

```cpp
typename varname = value;
```